# Objects Track using vision framework in iOS 11

Tags: swift, object-detection, coreml, avcapture, apple-vision

I want to detect object and track that object using vision framework. I am successfully done with detect objects and little bit with tracking also but I don't get so much accuracy with tracking.

I want much more accuracy while converting frames as its frequently lost the accuracy while track the objects.

Please check the below code for detect and track the objects:

```
import UIKit 
import AVFoundation
import Vision

class ViewController: UIViewController {

private lazy var captureSession: AVCaptureSession = {
   let session = AVCaptureSession()
   session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
   guard let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video),
       let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera) else 
           {
            return session
           }
    session.addInput(input)
    return session
 }()

private lazy var cameraLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = 
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)

private let handler = VNSequenceRequestHandler()
fileprivate var lastObservation: VNDetectedObjectObservation?

lazy var highlightView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    view.layer.borderWidth = 4
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

    view.layer.addSublayer(cameraLayer)
   view.addSubview(highlightView)

   let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
   output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: 
"queue"))
   captureSession.addOutput(output)

   captureSession.startRunning()

   let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
action: #selector(tapAction))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    cameraLayer.frame = view.bounds
}

   // MARK: - Actions

  @objc private func tapAction(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    highlightView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 120, height: 120)
    highlightView.center = recognizer.location(in: view)

    let originalRect = highlightView.frame
    var convertedRect = 
    cameraLayer.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: 
    originalRect)
    convertedRect.origin.y = 1 - convertedRect.origin.y

     lastObservation = VNDetectedObjectObservation(boundingBox: 
     convertedRect)
}

fileprivate func handle(_ request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let newObservation = request.results?.first as? 
VNDetectedObjectObservation else {
           return
        }
        self.lastObservation = newObservation
        var transformedRect = newObservation.boundingBox
        transformedRect.origin.y = 1 - transformedRect.origin.y
        let convertedRect = 
        self.cameraLayer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: 
       transformedRect)
        self.highlightView.frame = convertedRect
    }
}
}

 extension ViewController: 
 AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: 
   CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let pixelBuffer = 
    CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer),
            let observation = lastObservation else {
                return
        } 
        let request = VNTrackObjectRequest(detectedObjectObservation: 
    observation) { [unowned self] request, error in
            self.handle(request, error: error)
       }
       request.trackingLevel = .accurate
        do {
            try handler.perform([request], on: pixelBuffer)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
       }
       }
```

Any help will be appreciated!!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so good at vision and core ml, but apparently your code looks fine. One thing you can do is check when vision does not get any tracking in the buffer, you have to mark its property ***isLastFrame*** true if tracking request confidence value falls to 0.

```
  if !trackingRequest.isLastFrame {
      if observation.confidence > 0.7 {
          trackingRequest.inputObservation = observation
      } else {
                trackingRequest.isLastFrame = true
            }
          newTrackingRequests.append(trackingRequest)

   }
```

This way its easy to find out whether vision tracking request lost tracking object or it just tracking the wrong object.